# WordPress: How to store entities in plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin in WordPress that is about to store configurable entities. They are jobs to be done by Cron. There are plenty of them and each one has name, frequency and some additional data.

There are discussions how to store post-related data in plugins, whether to use `postmeta` table or own tables. It is officially adviced to use `postmeta` whenever possible. But what if those entities are not posts? I have 3 possibilities:

1. Use separate table(s) to store them
2. Use `options` table
3. Make those entities `posts` with custom post type

I used to keep this kind of information in `options` table, but how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you are trying to decide if you need a custom table or not, answer a simple question: does my data need indexes and fast searching? If yes - go with custom tables. If not - e.g.:

- this data is being read from database with the post itself - use postmeta
- this data is used rarely and is called directly by keys - use options

Else, if you need to store a lot of structured data, perform selects, sorts, or even joins etc - custom db table is your option. Read the docs and do it using core functions and features, like `db_delta()` function etc. There's nothing wrong in using custom db tables. Just do it right, the "WordPress way".

Comment: It doesn't quite answer my question. I don't read those data rarely, so `options` table is not great. My data is not post-related (but I could force it to use posts). And finally, it's not going to be lots of data. So neither of your suggestions seem relevant.

Comment: if it does not fit the most common strategies, then probably using custom table is the best option.